Rename a file matching two substrings in Bash with regex
I need to copy files and rename them.
replacing the "N" with another string that I have in an environment variable.
For the following file;
myFile_N_something.cfc_
I can do this with a for/do/done block, in a bash script using regex;
for files in *.cfc_;
do
        cp "$files" "${files/_N_/_$theID_}";
done

BUT...
I also need to strip out the trailing "_" from the very end of the filename, too, so it ultimately ends up being;
myFile_32_something.cfc
(assuming i have "32" in the environment variable)
I can of course do another separate step... But I am hoping to "UP" my regex skills and do it in one command, if it is possible.
As always thanks!

The parameter expansion substitution doesn't work with regexes, but patterns. They are far simpler than regexes, so using two steps is the only option. Also note that _$theID_ doesn't do what you think: it uses the variable $theID_, you probably need _${theID}_ instead.

Thanks @choroba for picking up the error in my env variable. But as you can see from the other answers, it is possible to do it in a single regex statement.

It's not a regex. Also, in "${files%%_N_*}_${theID}_${files//!(*.*)_}cfg", the substitution is used twice, not once.

Note that bash supports true regular expressions with the =~ operator of conditional expressions ([[ ... ]]); the nice aspect is that the test to skip non-matching file names comes for free:
for files in *.cfc_; do
  [[ $files =~ (.*)_N_(.*)_ ]] &&
  cp "$files" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}_${theID}_${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
done

With extended pattern matching (in a subshell to automatically restore the extglob option):
( shopt -s extglob
for files in *.cfc_; do
  cp "$files" "${files%%_N_*}_${theID}_${files//!(*.*)_}cfg"
done )

${files%%_N_*} is a regular substitution that deletes the longest suffix starting with _N_; in your example it leaves myFile. ${files//!(*.*)_} is an extended pattern-matching and substitution that replaces all _-terminated substrings not containing a period with the empty string; in your example this leaves something..
We could also split the file name on _ using IFS (in a subshell to automatically restore IFS):
for files in *.cfc_; do
  ( IFS=_; a=( $files ); cp "$files" "${a[0]}_${theID}_${a[2]}" )
done


If you have rename tool, try this
rename -n 's/_N_/_$ENV{theID}_/; s/_$//' *.cfc_

Remove -n if suggestions are correct.

@GavinBaumanis, if you have problems with rename see Why is the rename utility on Debian/Ubuntu different than the one on other distributions, like CentOS?.

I Did initially get it working with rename.
rename -E "s/_N_/"$theID"/" -E "s/.cfc_/.cfc/" *.cfc_;
I just wanted to be able to do it in Regex. But thanks very much for the suggestion.

While I would suggest to go with Renaud's solution as it is really neat, here is another solution idea:
variable="38";
ls -1 *cfc_|sed -r "s,^(.*_)N(_.*)_$,cp & \1$variable\2,e"

Basically get file names from ls -1 and
^(.*_)N(_.*)_ - starting from beginning of the line creates two capture groups
First one is until the _ , then a not captured "N", and the second one from the _ till the end of the line without the last _ character at the end of the line.
In sed the & means the whole matched string from the previous section which means the whole file name, then capturing group 1, followed by the value of the shell variable, followed by capturing group 2.
Sed e option will execute it. If you would like to see the whole command for each  execution then put an extra p next to the e (front or behind, doesn't matter). If you would like to see the command only then either you put an echo front of the cp in sed or you remove the e at the end of the sed.
